# How do I access the value in an object in an array in an object?

Tags: php, object

I'm trying to work with some web service's API.  It returns this massive object.  What I want to know is how to work with it such that I can say "The cost of [shiptypename] is [costfee]" for each of the elements.

I tried reading tutorials on objects and found various answers here on stack that seemed almost right, but I'm lost.  I gather it starts with:

```
 $result["rates"]->
```

but everything I've tried appending to that gives me errors :(

Here's the object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ask] => Success
    [message] => Success.
    [time] => 2015-10-19 14:36:12
    [rates] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 11.86
                    [costfee] => 11.86
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 7-20
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => NO
                    [classtype] => China Post
                    [classtypecode] => CPS
                    [shiptype] => WWAM
                    [shiptypename] => WWAM
                    [shiptypecnname] => ä¸­å›½é‚®æ”¿å¤–å›´å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆå¹³é‚®ï¼‰
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 11.86
                    [costfee] => 11.86
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 7-20
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => NO
                    [classtype] => China Post
                    [classtypecode] => CPS
                    [shiptype] => CNQM
                    [shiptypename] => CNQM
                    [shiptypecnname] => å?Žå?—å¿«é‚®å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆå¹³é‚®)
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 12.94
                    [costfee] => 12.94
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 7-20
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => NO
                    [classtype] => China Post
                    [classtypecode] => CPS
                    [shiptype] => CNAM
                    [shiptypename] => Air Mail by China Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => ä¸­å›½é‚®æ”¿å°?åŒ…(å¹³é‚®)
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 14
                    [costfee] => 14
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 7-20
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => NO
                    [classtype] => China Post
                    [classtypecode] => CPS
                    [shiptype] => HKBAM
                    [shiptypename] => Bulk Air Mail by Hongkong Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => é¦™æ¸¯é‚®æ”¿å°?åŒ…(å¹³é‚®)
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 14.6
                    [costfee] => 14.6
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 5-15
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => NO
                    [classtype] => China Post
                    [classtypecode] => CPS
                    [shiptype] => SWBAM
                    [shiptypename] => Bulk Air Mail by Swiss Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => ç‘žå£«é‚®æ”¿å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆå¹³é‚®ï¼‰
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 17.94
                    [costfee] => 17.94
                    [dealfee] => 0
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 6-10
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => NO
                    [classtype] => China Post
                    [classtypecode] => CPS
                    [shiptype] => DEAM2
                    [shiptypename] => Air Mail by Deutsch Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => å¾·å›½é‚®æ”¿å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆå¹³é‚®)
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 20.5
                    [costfee] => 20.5
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 8
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 7-20
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Registered Postal
                    [classtypecode] => CRP
                    [shiptype] => WWRAM
                    [shiptypename] => WWRAM
                    [shiptypecnname] => ä¸­å›½é‚®æ”¿å¤–å›´å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆæŒ‚å?·ï¼‰
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 20.5
                    [costfee] => 20.5
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 8
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 7-20
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Registered Postal
                    [classtypecode] => CRP
                    [shiptype] => CNQMR
                    [shiptypename] => CNQMR
                    [shiptypecnname] => å?Žå?—å¿«é‚®å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆæŒ‚å?·ï¼‰
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 21.65
                    [costfee] => 21.65
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 8
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 7-20
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Registered Postal
                    [classtypecode] => CRP
                    [shiptype] => CNRAM
                    [shiptypename] => Registered Air Mail by China Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => ä¸­å›½é‚®æ”¿å°?åŒ…(æŒ‚å?·)
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 24.77
                    [costfee] => 24.77
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 8-15
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => NO
                    [classtype] => China Post
                    [classtypecode] => CPS
                    [shiptype] => SFCQM3
                    [shiptypename] => SFCQM3
                    [shiptypecnname] => å¿«é‚®ä¸‰çº§å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆå¹³é‚®ï¼‰
                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 29.76
                    [costfee] => 29.76
                    [dealfee] => 0
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 6-10
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Registered Postal
                    [classtypecode] => CRP
                    [shiptype] => DERAM2
                    [shiptypename] => Registered Air Mail by Deutsch Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => å¾·å›½é‚®æ”¿å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆæŒ‚å?·ï¼‰
                )

            [11] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 30.34
                    [costfee] => 30.34
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 15
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 5-15
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Registered Postal
                    [classtypecode] => CRP
                    [shiptype] => SWBRAM
                    [shiptypename] => Registered Bulk Air Mail by Swiss Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => ç‘žå£«é‚®æ”¿å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆæŒ‚å?·ï¼‰
                )

            [12] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 31.5
                    [costfee] => 31.5
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 15
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 7-20
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Registered Postal
                    [classtypecode] => CRP
                    [shiptype] => HKBRAM
                    [shiptypename] => Registered Bulk Air Mail by Hongkong Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => é¦™æ¸¯é‚®æ”¿å°?åŒ…(æŒ‚å?·)
                )

            [13] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 32.51
                    [costfee] => 32.51
                    [dealfee] => 0
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 7.0-10.0
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => USEXP
                    [shiptypename] => US and CA Express Line
                    [shiptypecnname] => ç¾ŽåŠ ä¸“çº¿
                )

            [14] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 35.43
                    [costfee] => 35.43
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 8-15
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Registered Postal
                    [classtypecode] => CRP
                    [shiptype] => SFCQM3R
                    [shiptypename] => SFCQM3R
                    [shiptypecnname] => å¿«é‚®ä¸‰çº§å°?åŒ…ï¼ˆæŒ‚å?·ï¼‰
                )

            [15] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 38.79
                    [costfee] => 38.79
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 5-15
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => NO
                    [classtype] => China Post
                    [classtypecode] => CPS
                    [shiptype] => SFCQM1
                    [shiptypename] => Air Mail by UK Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => å¿«é‚®å°?åŒ…ä¸€çº§å¹³é‚®
                )

            [16] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 102.18
                    [costfee] => 102.18
                    [dealfee] => 2
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 5-15
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Registered Postal
                    [classtypecode] => CRP
                    [shiptype] => SFCQM1R
                    [shiptypename] => Registered Air Mail by UK Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => å¿«é‚®å°?åŒ…ä¸€çº§æŒ‚å?·
                )

            [17] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 122.01
                    [costfee] => 122.01
                    [dealfee] => 9.95
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 8.06
                    [deliverytime] => 2-4
                    [isweight] => YES
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => CNUPS
                    [shiptypename] => UPS in China
                    [shiptypecnname] => ä¸­å›½UPS
                )

            [18] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 150.57
                    [costfee] => 150.57
                    [dealfee] => 9.95
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 12.2
                    [deliverytime] => 2-7
                    [isweight] => YES
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => HKDHL1
                    [shiptypename] => DHL1 in HongKong
                    [shiptypecnname] => é¦™æ¸¯DHL1
                )

            [19] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 156.14
                    [costfee] => 156.14
                    [dealfee] => 9.95
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 12.68
                    [deliverytime] => 2-7
                    [isweight] => YES
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => HKDHL
                    [shiptypename] => DHL in HongKong
                    [shiptypecnname] => é¦™æ¸¯DHL
                )

            [20] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 170.68
                    [costfee] => 170.68
                    [dealfee] => 9.95
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 11.21
                    [deliverytime] => 4-6
                    [isweight] => YES
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => CNSFEDEX
                    [shiptypename] => Fedex International Economy Service in China
                    [shiptypecnname] => ä¸­å›½FedExç»?æµŽåž‹
                )

            [21] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 177.95
                    [costfee] => 177.95
                    [dealfee] => 9.95
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 3-8
                    [isweight] => YES
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => SZEMS
                    [shiptypename] => Express Mail Service by Shenzhen Branch Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => ä¸­å›½EMS
                )

            [22] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 180.6
                    [costfee] => 180.6
                    [dealfee] => 0
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 2.0-7.0
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => HKEMS
                    [shiptypename] => Express Mail Service by Hong Kong Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => é¦™æ¸¯EMS
                )

            [23] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 185.27
                    [costfee] => 185.27
                    [dealfee] => 9.95
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 12.23
                    [deliverytime] => 2-4
                    [isweight] => YES
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => CNFEDEX
                    [shiptypename] => Fedex International Priority Service in China
                    [shiptypecnname] => ä¸­å›½FedExä¼˜å…ˆåž‹
                )

            [24] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 197.68
                    [costfee] => 197.68
                    [dealfee] => 9.95
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 0
                    [deliverytime] => 4-10
                    [isweight] => NO
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => SGEMS
                    [shiptypename] => Express Mail Service by Singapore Post
                    [shiptypecnname] => æ–°åŠ å?¡EMS
                )

            [25] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalfee] => 201.15
                    [costfee] => 201.15
                    [dealfee] => 9.95
                    [regfee] => 0
                    [addons] => 13.75
                    [deliverytime] => 2-5
                    [isweight] => YES
                    [iftracking] => YES
                    [classtype] => China Express Mail
                    [classtypecode] => CRE
                    [shiptype] => HKUPS
                    [shiptypename] => UPS in Hongkong
                    [shiptypecnname] => é¦™æ¸¯UPS
                )

        )

)
```

Addressing assertion this is a duplicate:  the is specifically because I'm getting lost in the LEVEL.  The Q you say is a dupe is an Array.  Sorry if I'm confused, but that's WHY I'm asking!

Comment: paste here what you get inside full object

Comment: Really?  Ok.  Didn't think that would be kosher.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to iterate over the object:

```
foreach ($object->rates as $rate) {
    print 'The cost of '. $rate->shiptypename . ' is ' . $rate->costfee . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Each rate is a further object so that won't quite work. foreach ($object->rates as $rate) { print $rate->shiptypename; }. The trick Rizier123 is to look at whether it says 'Array' or 'stdClass Object'. If it is Array use square braces [0] [1] etc or loop through them with foreach and if it is an object use the ->

Comment: @scott I edited the answer, I somehow missed that, thank you!

Comment: Ahhhhh... ok, thanks!  I was over complicating it I think  I ended up having a foreach inside a foreach and it was a mess